# UICollectionViewCell with UITapGestureRecognizer action is just called once with state 3

Tags: ios, objective-c

My implementation is based on a UICollectionViewController. I tried to implement a touch behavior on the UiTableCell to recognize the touchdown and up event. My solution is based on a little research but i'm not sure it's the proper way to get it done.

I attach UITapGestureRecognizer on every table cell:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *homeItem = self.homeItems[indexPath.row];
    HomeCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:homeItem[@"cell"] forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellClicked:)];
    //NSArray* recognizers = [cell gestureRecognizers];
    //    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

//    // Make the default gesture recognizer wait until the custom one fails.
//    for (UIGestureRecognizer* aRecognizer in recognizers) {
//        if ([aRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]])
//            [aRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapGesture];
//    }

    [cell addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    return cell;
}
```

But the declared action is just called once for the recognizer state 3 (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)

```
- (void)cellClicked:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    Log(@"cellClicked with state: %d", [recognizer state]);
}
```

This all is may caused by the default implementation of the CollectionView behavior.

I'm new to objc and ios development so i'm not sure what i can do to get done my implementation to change the styling on the cell via states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the [*Event Handling Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW9), there are two types of gesture recognizers: *discrete* and *continuous*.  A `UITapGestureRecognizer` is discrete, which means it sends just one action message when it recognizes its gesture.

Discrete recognizers like `UITapGestureRecognizer` send the action in state `UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized`, which is an alias for `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`.

If you want to recognize the touch-down and touch-up events separately, your best bet is probably just to use a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` (or whatever view you need detect the events on), and override the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and related messages.